# Python __del__ method for classes?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, magic-methods

I'm interested in adding some hooks to my code when a class (as opposed to an instance) is garbage collected or otherwise falls out of memory. Here is some example code:

```
def make_objects():
    class A(type):
        def __del__(cls):
            print 'class deleted'
    class B(object):
        __metaclass__ = A
        def __del__(self):
            print 'instance deleted'
    b = B()

print 'making objects'
make_objects()
print 'finished'
```

I was hoping to see:

- making objects
- instance deleted
- class deleted
- finished

But instead all I saw was:

- making objects
- instance deleted
- finished

If I modify the code to explicitly call `del B`, it makes no difference:

```
def make_objects():
    class A(type):
        def __del__(cls):
            print 'class deleted'
    class B(object):
        __metaclass__ = A
        def __del__(self):
            print 'instance deleted'
    del B
```

Output:

- making objects
- finished

My question is: is it possible to hook into an object being deleted? Is there something preventing the class `B` from being deleted that I may not be aware of?

Comment: Note that there is a difference between deleting *the class* and deleting *an instance*. Just naming the first parameter `cls` **does not** a classmethod make.

Comment: I defined the override on the metaclass, which is, as I understand, the way to override magic-methods at the class-level. I am aware the argument name has no affect.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that there are other references to `B` that prevent its garbage collection. For example, if I have `make_objects` return a weak reference (`weakref.ref(B)`) to `B`, then call `sys.getrefcount()` on the return value, it prints 3. This means that even after `make_objects` has returned, there are still 3 references to the class `B` hanging around. If the interpreter exits before those references are released, `B.__del__` is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: chepner, I think you're spot on. In my testing there were some references hanging around. Using gc.get_referrers() it looks like they are: `<attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>, (<class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)`. Seems like the answer is, there is no answer?